# Invoking main of a class that extends Activity

Tags: java, android

Why isn't it possible to invoke main method of any class inherited from android.app.Activity?

Android v6.*, I use Android Studio to build apk.
Here's the sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends android.app.Activity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello there");
    }
}
```

Launching the code:

```
adb shell dalvikvm -Djava.library.path=<.apk location> -classpath <.apk location>/app-debug.apk com.example.me.myapplication.MainActivity
```

I observe SIGSEGV (dalvikvm32) and SIGBUS (dalvikvm) via logcat.

Edit: To all the commenters - of course I know how to write both console and GUI applications. Still android.app.Activity is a regular class. And still dalvikvm loads a specified class and invokes main method of it.
I'm doing this not to launch gui from console but more for academical purposes.

Comment: I don't think Android uses the main method

Comment: It doesn't indeed. Go read the Android getting started tutorials.

Comment: I sometimes use a main method to quickly check/test something on my pc, but it's not really possible to run it on an Android device. To run it locally, right click in the code and click whatever has "Ctrl+Shift+F10" next to it (thanks muscle memory).